# Javascript Canvas + objects/functions

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas, scope

I'm trying to teach myself javascript and so I decided to do a project with HTML5 and canvas, but have come across a bug in my code that I can't figure out. I declare my context as a variable c, but in any functions and object definitions that reference c, things like c.beginPath(), are showing up as being undefined. However, if such a reference would work outside of the function. I'm following an online tutorial on canvas pretty closely, and I can't see any difference between what I'm doing and what the tutorial is doing that would make my code not run. Most of my code is below, and calls to the draw method are what's giving me trouble. Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

// circle object
function Circle(x, y, dx, dy, r, color) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.r = r;
  this.color = color;

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    c.strokeStyle = this.color;
    c.stroke();
    c.fill();
  }

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.x + this.r > w || this.x - this.r < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y + this.r > h || this.y - this.r < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
    }

    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;

    this.draw();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you aren't doing I believe that may have you confused.

You have a class like structure of Circle.  I'm guessing this is what is intended given your code, but you have not created an instance of that class anywhere.

You need to create a new reference of that class, and then invoke the methods you want off that class in the new object.

I wrote up a fiddle for you using your own code.

Something like this:

```
var j = new Circle(100, 100, 200, 200, 20, 'red');
j.draw();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wu3dcyfm/

Comment: Also, given your code, you're referencing strokeStyle, this will only paint the border of the circle.

If you want to paint the innards, you need to modify c.fillStyle = 'somecolor'

Comment: I feel like you really want to learn some proper OO mechanics too, so I took the liberty of removing all of your global references and made everything self contained within the class.

https://jsfiddle.net/hdx799py/

If you want to take it further, completely remove the canvas out of the html itself, and create it within the javascript too.